# How to display username in home.php page after login

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner. I dont have any professional degree on coding. I have learnt through internet only. I have developed a few pages which will be connected to database. I have tried to login using username and password and it successfully redirects to the home page. Now I want the username to be displayed on the home page after login. please help. what modifications do I need to do ??

login_save.php code is as below-

```html
<?php

function SignIn($loginname,$pass) {
//require_once '../../common/createdbconn.php';

$login_id='';
$login_status='';
$error_message= '';

if(!empty($loginname) && !empty($pass)){ //checking the 'user' name and password, is it empty or have some text 
  
  $login_id=validate_login($loginname,$pass);  
  if ($login_id != '') {  
  
   $login_status=$login_id;
  }
  
 else {
  //empty check
  $error_message=NO_USERNAME;
  $login_status=$error_message;
  
 }
 return $login_status;
 
}
}
function validate_login($loginname,$pass) {
 require '../../common/createdbconn.php';
 // validate user
 $sql="SELECT id, fullname from m_user where login_name='$loginname' and password='$pass'";
 //$sql="SELECT mu.id as id, mu.fullname as fullname, mu.office_id as office_id, xurm.role_id as role_id from m_user mu, x_user_role_mapping xurm where mu.id = xurm.user_id and mu.login_name='$loginname' and mu.password='$pass'";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 $login_id=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
 session_start();
 $sessionid = session_id();
 $sql_sessionid="update m_user set session_id='$sessionid' where login_name='$loginname'";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql_sessionid);
 $_SESSION['login_id']=$login_id[0];
 $_SESSION['fullname']=$login_id[1];
 $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
 $_SESSION['loginname']=$loginname;
 return $login_id[0];
} 

?>
```

login_action.php code

```html
<?php 

require_once '../../common/createdbconn.php';
require_once '../model/login_save.php';

$loginname=$_POST["user"];
$password=$_POST["pass"];
$pass=md5($password);
$login_status='';

$login_status=SignIn($loginname,$pass);

if ($login_status=='' || $login_status=='NO_USERNAME') { // Validation passed
 session_start(); //starting the session for user profile page  
 $error ="Username or Password is invalid";
 header("location:../view/login.php?session_id=".session_id());
}
else{
 header("location:../../cbs/view/home.php?login_status=$login_status");
 session_destroy();
}
?>
```

login.php code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php 
require '../../common/createdbconn.php';
?>

<html>
 <head>
 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CBS HELPDESK,ASSAM CIRCLE</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="../../images/IP.png" type="image/png" sizes="100x56">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <img src="../../images/indiapost.jpg" style="width:1600px;height:120px;">
  <h1>Welcome to Circle Processing Centre-Assam</h1>
  
  <div style="color: Red;">
   <p>
    <?php
    echo (isset($_GET['login_status']) ? htmlentities($_GET['login_status'], ENT_QUOTES) : '');
    ?>
   </p>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="container">
   
    <h2>Login to Continue</h2>


    <form method="post" action="../controller/login_action.php" class="form">    
     <input id="user" name="user" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your UserID">
     <input id="pass" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
     <button id="login" name="login"  type="submit">LogIn</button>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

home.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>CBS HELPDESK,ASSAM CIRLCE</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/home_style.css">
   <link rel="icon" href="../../images/IP.png" type="image/png" sizes="100x56">
   
   
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var tmonth=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
       function GetClock(){
       var d=new Date();
       var nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getYear();
       if(nyear<1000) nyear+=1900;
       var nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes(),nsec=d.getSeconds();
       if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin
       if(nsec<=9) nsec="0"+nsec;
       document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+tmonth[nmonth]+" "+ndate+", "+nyear+" "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+"";
       }
       window.onload=function(){
       GetClock();
       setInterval(GetClock,1000);
       }
</script>
   
 </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Circle Processing Centre(CBS)<br>     
   O/O The Chief Postmaster General, Assam-781001</h1>
   <header>
    <marquee style="font-size:50px;" behavior="scroll" direction="left">CBS Offices as on <?php echo date("d-m-y");?> = 507</marquee>    
   </header>
   <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="../../user_requests.php">User Related Requests</a></li>
    <li><a href="cbs_offices.php">List of CBS Offices in Assam</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../migration_plans.php">Migration Plans</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../atm_sites.php">ATM Sites-Assam</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../faqs_instructions.php">FAQs/Instrcutions/Orders</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../contact_us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../login/view/login.php">Logout</a></li></ul>
   </nav>
   
   <section>
  <table>
  <tr>
   <th>Division</th>
   <th>No of Total Offices</th>
   <th>No of CBS Offices</th>
   <th>Achievement in %</th>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </section>
   
   <footer>
   <div id="clockbox">   
   </div>   
   </footer>
  
  </body>
   
  </html>
```

Comment: I suggest you look into http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php so you can get it right from the start instead of making the same mistakes as many do when first learning php. I could easily log into that site without knowing the password. After that I suggest you look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and `password_verify`

Answer (score 1):

In home.php, you should first check if the session exists and redirect to the login page (if it's not already done).

Then you could display the ursername like this anywhere you want :

```
<div><?php echo $_SESSION['fullname']; ?></div>
```

or

```
<div><?= $_SESSION['fullname'] ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are saving logged in user name in `$_SESSION['loginname']=$loginname;`
Use `session_start();` at the starting of login_save.php and `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the starting of home.php
User name you can call in home.php using

```
$name=$_SESSION['loginname']; 
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using login_name as username in your table.
You store login_name in session so simply display the username from session.
**Don't forget start session on home page and always start session on the top of page.You start session in the middle of code on login_save.php**
Use this code on your home page

```html
<?php
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['login_name']; 
?>
```